# How to share objects/methods between controllers without circular references?

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Pretty straightforward question. Currently, what I do when I need to access objects' methods throughout most of the application, I do this in `app.js`

```
Ext.define('Utils', {
    statics: {
        myMethod: function() {
            return 'myResult'; 
        }
    }
});
```

This works, but when I build the application, I get a warning about a circular reference (app.js of course needs all the other controller classes, but then said classes refer back to app.js).

I thought of using a package including a .js file that has all the objects/methods, but sometimes, within these methods I'll need access to the `Ext` namespace so that won't work.

Is there any better way to do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: use a provider, such as a service: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: @sgroves have any examples ?

Comment: nope. that's why this is a comment. you can google for examples (or look at that link).

Comment: @sgroves angular isn't tagged here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not define the class `Utils` inside `app.js`. Each `Ext.define` statement should be in it's own file. Also the classname should be prefixed with your app name.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Utils', {
    statics: {
        myMethod: function() {
            return 'myResult'; 
        }
    }
});
```

should therefore be found in the file `app/Utils.js`. When compiling your sources into a compiled `app.js`, Sencha Cmd will take care of the proper ordering in the final file. The `requires` and `uses` directives give you enough flexibility to define any dependences between your classes.

Read all the docs about MVC to get a clear understanding.

Comment: Works wonder. I guess that's why it's important to pick a meaningful app name, but not overly long.