# ExtJS - Access variables from different files

Tags: javascript, extjs, global-variables, anonymous-function

What I want to do is adding several panels to a tab panel. The tab panel and the panels are in different files (File1, File2, File3) and the code is inside anonymous functions. What is the easiest and/or best way to make this work?

main.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="File1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="File2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="File3.js"></script>
```

File1.js

```
Ext.application({    
    name: 'app',    
    launch: function() {
        var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            id: 'tabPanel',
            ...
        });
    }
});
```

File2.js

```
function() {
    var panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        ....
    });
    tabPanel.add(panel1); // Of course not working since tabPanel of File1.js is private
}
```

File3.js

```
function() {
    var panel2 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        ....
    });
    tabPanel.add(panel2); // Of course not working since tabPanel of File1.js is private
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are simply trying to separate UI element definitions in different physical files, you could and should use views.

In view/TabPanel.js:

```
Ext.define('YourApplicationName.TabPanel.view', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.TabPanel',
    itemId: 'TabPanel' //never use 'id', let ExtJS use it.
    ...
});
```

In view/Panel1.js:

```
Ext.define('YourApplicationName.Panel1.view', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.Panel1',
    itemId: 'Panel1'
    ...
});
```

One your views are created (with of course their respective controllers ie: `YourApplicationName.TabPanel.controller`), from any controller you will be able to access the components using `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` such as

```
var component = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[itemId=TabPanel]')[0]; //assuming only one item has such itemId.
```

And in Ext 4.x+ (I think) the `main.html` (actually `index.html`) should be generated by Sencha Cmd (sencha app generate)

```
sencha generate app MyApp /path/to/MyApp
```

And on the other hand, if you are simply trying to have objects accessible throughout all of your ExtJS application, see my question and its answer

[How to share objects/methods between controllers without circular references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916742/how-to-share-objects-methods-between-controllers-without-circular-references)